# Un árbol desbalanceado fue escrito usando document.write()

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hola estoy aprendiendo funciones de javascript y escribi un codigo que funciona pero la consola de firefox me da una advertencia:

> Un árbol desbalanceado fue escrito usando document.write() causando que los datos de la red deban ser reprocesados. Para más información https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing

Ingrese en esa pagina pero no tiene contenido.
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
function calculadora(numero1, numero2, mostrar = false) {

if (mostrar == false) {
    console.log("Suma: " + (numero1 + numero2));
    console.log("Resta: " + (numero1 - numero2));
    console.log("Multiplicacion: " + (numero1 * numero2));
    console.log("Division: " + (numero1 / numero2));

    console.log("*************************************");

} else {
    
    document.write("Suma: " + (numero1 + numero2));
    document.write("Resta: " + (numero1 - numero2));
    document.write("Multiplicacion: " + (numero1 * numero2));
    document.write("Division: " + (numero1 / numero2));
    document.write("*************************************");
    
    


}
```

}

calculadora(8, 8);
calculadora(5, 5, true);

Como podria resolver esa advertencia? por que esta desbalanceado el arbol?

Comment: La función `document.write` es una **mala práctica**, podrías simplemente alterar el `innerHTML` de `document.body`

Comment: Por qué utilizas `document.write()`? Siempre es buena idea checar la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write)

Comment: Tal como dicen los comentarios de arriba, deberías revisar la documentación porque al ejecutar `document.write()` lo que haces es reescribir todo el contenido del documento.

Comment: Diría que el árbol está desbalanceado, porque el _document_ es un documento HTML, y tu no escribes nada de etiquetas del _markup_ que compone HTML.. Podrías  escribir todo dentro de una etiqueta `<p></p>`, como mínimo.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como habrás leído en los comentarios de tu pregunta, no es recomendable usar [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write) de esa forma, pues reescribes todo el documento *html* (y lo haces mas de una vez), como solución podrías hacer referencia a un elemento del `<body>` (o a este directamente) y  agregarle el contenido que quieras mostrar con [innerHTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText):

```
<body>
    
    <div id="contenido"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function calculadora(numero1, numero2, mostrar = false) {
            const contenidoVar = document.getElementById("contenido");
            if (mostrar == false) {
                console.log("Suma: " + (numero1 + numero2));
                console.log("Resta: " + (numero1 - numero2));
                console.log("Multiplicacion: " + (numero1 * numero2));
                console.log("Division: " + (numero1 / numero2));
                console.log("*************************************");
            } else { 
                contenidoVar.innerHTML += "<p>Suma: " + (numero1 + numero2) + "</p>";
                contenidoVar.innerHTML += "<p>Resta: " + (numero1 - numero2) + "</p>";
                contenidoVar.innerHTML += "<p>Multiplicacion: " + (numero1 * numero2) + "</p>";
                contenidoVar.innerHTML += "<p>Division: " + (numero1 / numero2)+ "</p>";
                contenidoVar.innerHTML += "<p>*************************************</p>";
            }
        }

        calculadora(8, 8); 
        calculadora(5, 5, true);

    </script>
</body>
```

En este código he creado una etiqueta `<div>`(por gusto propio) con un `id="contenido"`, para poder hacerle referencia dentro del script usando el método [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), luego en el script guardo esta referencia en la variable `contenidoVar` y en el `else` le voy agregando poco a poco el contenido que quieres mostrar(dentro de etiquetas `<p>` cada uno para que no estén en la misma linea)